# Web Scraping With Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access the `HTML` code on a site [forexfactory.com](https://www.forexfactory.com/) and return all span tags with a class of `worse` and `better`.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.forexfactory.com/#closed")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find("table", class_="calendar__table")

Wnews = []
Bnews = []
Tnews = []

for row in table.find_all('tr', class_='calendar__row--grey'):

currency = row.find("td", class_="currency")
# print(currency.prettify()) # before get text
currency = currency.get_text(strip=True)

actual = row.find("td", class_="actual")
actual = actual.get_text(strip=True)

impact = row.find("span", class_="worse")
try:
    impactW = impact.get_text(strip=True)
except AttributeError:
    continue

impact2 = row.find("span", class_="better")
try:
    impactB = impact2.get_text(strip=True)
except AttributeError:
    continue

# print(impact)

# news.append(currency)news.append(actual)

if currency == "GBP":

    actual = row.find("td", class_="actual")
    actual = actual.get_text(strip=True)

    Tnews.append(currency)

    forecast = row.find("td", class_="forecast")
    forecast = forecast.get_text(strip=True)

    Wnews.append(impactW)
    Bnews.append(impactB)

    print(impact2)
```

`print(impact2)` is returning multiple all the span tags with `class = "Revised Better"` instead of just `better`.  What I'm writing wrong ?

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Comment: @Rehan : check out my answer.I believe you have beautiful soup 4.7.1 +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the span tag of class `worse` only try below code.with **css** selector.

```
worsedata=[item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('table.calendar__table tr.calendar__row--grey span.worse:not(.revised)')]
print(worsedata)
```

**Output**:

```
['0.0%', '-0.2%', '-0.3%', '-1.7%', '0.1%', '-1.2%']
```

---

To get `span tag` class only **better**.

```
betterdata=[item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('table.calendar__table tr.calendar__row--grey span.better:not(.revised)')]
print(betterdata)
```

**Output**:

```
['1.9%', '-5.3B']
```

Comment: Yes this does work thank you.  However I am trying to only return the news for a specific currency, I implemented your code for worse data into the if statement for accomplish this but when i print(worsedata) outside of the for loop it only returns one piece of data (should return two). @KunduK

Comment: Sorry mate away now.You can post which data you want to get with news on comment section I will come back tomorrow.By the time you can research if you able to crack.